# ImageView setImageResource not working

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have a custom class that inherits from `RelativeLayout`. I have an `ImageButton` called `control_btn` that's defined and added to the layout in an `init()` method. On the `onDraw`, I have the following code (among other things):

```
    control_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_new);
    control_btn.getLayoutParams().width = getPixels(20);
    control_btn.getLayoutParams().height = getPixels(20);
    control_btn.setX(getPixels(0));
    control_btn.setY(getPixels(10));
    control_btn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    control_btn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    control_btn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    control_btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    control_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            control_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            Log.d("WTH", "clicked");
        }
    });
```

However, the image never changes, despite getting the log entry.
Further, I have another `ImageButton` with exactly the same code whose image DOES change (also inside the custom class).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: try to put setImageResource into init() method

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius. I thought because I was only changing one view, the onDraw wouldn't be called. Please say that as an answer so I can mark it as correct, and thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `setImageResource` into `init()` method, then problem will be fixed.